# CORS - Is it a client-side thing, a server-side thing, or a transport level thing?

Tags: javascript, cors

I am trying to understand [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). From my understanding, it empowers you to limit which domains can access a resource on your server. However, this doesn't seem like the full story. For example, I have a web service without CORS enabled. I cannot hit this web service from my web application via jQuery (the app is running on localhost). However, I can hit the web service from Postman. So, I'm a bit confused. Is there some extra client side work that involves CORS?

Answer (score 179):

The server is responsible for reporting the allowed origins. The web browser is responsible for enforcing that requests are only sent from allowed domains.

[CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) is applied to requests when an [Origin header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin) is included in the request. This includes requests made from JavaScript and POST requests. It's not applied all resources. The origin is the protocol, host and port that is making the request. Requests made by JavaScript use the origin that loaded the JavaScript, not the origin that it was loaded from.

When CORS is not enabled a browser will rely on the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). The same origin policy is only applied to scripts. The browser will only allow scripts to be loaded from same origin as the loaded page. The same origin policy is assumed when not origins are explicitly allowed.

An HTTP client other than a browser won't use either the same origin policy or CORS. Requests made from these other HTTP clients don't have an origin. Unless the Postman desktop app emulates a browser it will be able to make requests to any URL.

CORS and the same origin policy are needed because a browser does not implicitly trust the websites it visits to make requests to other websites. They don't protect the origin site, they protect the site receiving the cross origin requests. This is why the allowed origins are up to the targeted server.

Without these policies a simple script that repeatedly loads a website could be distributed by ad networks or script injection and then any browser loading the script would contribute to a denial of service attack on the website. With CORS and the same origin policy a browser will limit the impact of this script.

Another important protection CORS provides is to protect against [Cross-site request forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). It prevents a site from making some types of requests to another site. These requests would be made using any previously created tokens, such as session tokens.

CORS by example:

A web browser loads a page from `www.example.com`. The page includes a script that makes a request to `www.example.org`. The origin of the request is `www.example.com`. The browser either makes the request or sends an `OPTIONS` request first (the preflight request). When the server at `www.example.org` receives a request from an origin other than `www.example.org` it responds with a response header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` which tells the browser the origins allowed to make requests. It may also respond with other headers like `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` that can restrict the types of allowed requests. When the browser is told what origins are allowed it will block future requests from disallowed origins.

Comment: Is CORS a security thing then? I have a hard time viewing it as a security component if its the web browser's responsibility to enforce that that request are only sent from allowed domains.

Comment: @ZachTempleton CORS is a way to relax the same origin policy. The same origin policy is used because browsers don't trust the sites they visit or the content they load. It prevents one site from maliciously interfering with another site.

Comment: So the main purpose is to secure servers from DoS attacks coming from browsers?

Comment: @jpenna no it also helps prevent cross-site request forgery attacks. If a site uses a cookie to authenticate without the same origin policy injected scripts could make requests using that authentication https://medium.com/@electra_chong/what-is-cors-what-is-it-used-for-308cafa4df1a

Comment: Yes, I'm also having a hard time seeing this as security. What if I just write my own web-browser and I just ignore the CORS headers?

Comment: Regarding denial of service — in what cases will the browser preemptively block identical AJAX requests after an initial CORS violation? I just tested this scenario and it didn't seem to be the case. Also, CORS is only enforced for AJAX, but not page elements `<img src="http://example.com/>`. So I do not understand how the same-origin policy can mitigate denial of service?

Comment: @redigaffi, then nobody would use that browser :) — but you don't actually have write your own (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome). The thing is, it would be extremely dangerous/negligent to log into your bank account using a browser that it is not respecting the same-origin policy. The browser is loading "random" scripts from all over the internet, and without the same-origin policy in effect those scripts could compromise the information that you have entrusted to your browser.

Comment: I am new and confused with this. What if example.org guy embeds script in web page that makes request to example.org and the same guy also sets cors enabled on example.org?

Comment: When an example.org page makes a request to example.org the origin is the same as the request so no CORS rules are applied. The Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is ignored

Comment: "When the browser is told what origins are allowed it will block future requests from disallowed origins".  I have a question about the very first request. Afaiu it returns Access-Control-Allow-Origin header together with the content, and browser blocks the content on the client side, correct? Server itself gives the content. And if the 1st request is POST, than browser learns it after something is already added, correct? I know about preflight requests, but they are applied to PUT and DELETE, not POST and GET.

Comment: One thing people are struggling with in this thread .... CORS is designed to allow exceptions to the same-origin-policy (SOP) that prevents attacks where the user is not aware that the resource their browser is fetching is coming from a different domain (e.g. XSS attack). 

These policies are designed to prevent unauthorized access to a different domain, not deliberate authorized access from something like Postman. Hence the browser being the enforcer of CORS as it is for SOP.

Answer (score 15):

It's a bit of both actually. Your browser will prevent CORS requests unless the origin of the request (i.e the referrer URL domain) is in a white list on the destination, or the destination approves all requests regardless of origin.

In both cases, the required header (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) is added which tells the browser that it's ok to send the request to the destination.

This ensures that people with malicious intent cannot send requests to another domain without the the user knowing about it.

Comment: What do you mean by "This ensures that people with malicious intent cannot send requests to another domain without the the user knowing about it"? The malicious person could set their own server with CORS enabled and send the users information there, using XSS for example, and the user would never know.

Comment: Yes but you would have to load a compromised website for that to happen. CORS isn't a magic pill that prevents everything but it is a mitigation to XSS