# Option request fails with 404

Tags: vue.js, playframework, cors, axios

I am trying to send a GET request from my frontend to an API application. Both are running on my local machine. This is how it's built right now:

```
backend <===> frontend <=x=> API application
```

All three parts are running independently from each other in their own docker container and are only communicating with each other via HTTP-requests.

As shown in the top image, the connection between `backend` and `frontend` works fine, but between `frontend` and `API application` does not.

The stack consists of:

- `frontend`: Node server with vue-js and for requests I use axios
- `API application`: Scala with Play Framework 2.5.14

The API application itself works just find when I send a request to her via curl like this:

```
curl -X GET api-application.docker/api/user?userId=1 \
-H "Authorization: key" -H "Accept: Application/Json"
```

But when I call it from frontend, I get a 404 on the OPTIONS call. It also gives me a warning in Firefox related to CORS header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the
remote resource at http://api-application.docker:9000/api/user?userId=1
(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

Therefore I first went into the api application's `application.conf` and added

```
play.filters.cors {
  allowedOrigins = ["*"]
}
```

I also tried to exchange the asterisk for `http://frontend.docker:8080`

This didn't work, so I deleted that entry again and added this line instead:

```
play.filters.disabled += "play.filters.cors.CORSFilter"
```

Still no change at all. Now I am wondering if I misunderstood the connection between OPTIONS and CORS? Or did I turn it off wrong? Can anyone help me out?

EDIT:
More stuff I tried while waiting for answers, all without success:

I changed the entry in `application.conf` to:

```
play.filters.cors {
  allowedOrigins = null
}
```

Comment: doesn't look like you've followed this https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/CorsFilter#Enabling-the-CORS-filter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

404 on OPTIONS request indicates your `CORSFilter` is not enabled. Since you are using Play 2.5 you can [enable](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/CorsFilter#Enabling-the-CORS-filter) it by adding

```
libraryDependencies += filters
```

to your `build.sbt`, and by creating the following `app/Filters.scala` file:

```
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.http.DefaultHttpFilters
import play.filters.cors.CORSFilter

class Filters @Inject() (corsFilter: CORSFilter)
  extends DefaultHttpFilters(corsFilter)
```

By default everything is allowed so there is no need to modify `application.conf` until you decide to start locking down access. You should NOT add `play.filters.disabled += "play.filters.cors.CORSFilter"` as this disables CORS support.

The reason why your `curl` request works fine is because non-browser HTTP clients do not enforce Same-origin policy (see [related SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36958999/cors-is-it-a-client-side-thing-a-server-side-thing-or-a-transport-level-thin#answer-36959539)), thus CORS does not apply in the case of `curl`.

404 on OPTIONS request means that the following route is not found:

```
OPTIONS api-application.docker/api/user
```

The browser automatically sends this [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) before sending the corresponding GET request. This OPTIONS route will be automatically taken care of by Play's CORS support once enabled.

Comment: This did work perfectly. Thank you a lot. I also had my filters in a non-standard path which I linked to in my application.conf. But after refactoring everything to your suggestion, it does work like a charm.