# HTTP Request to external API works with .NET, but not with React (CORS problems)

Tags: reactjs, .net, http, post

I want to make HTTP Post request to external API, but as I'm trying to do it from React with axios I have a CORS error (No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource). At the same time while making this request in .NET everything seems to be ok.  I don't have a clue why is it working like this, so maybe someone can figure it out.

React request:

```
var bodyFormData = new FormData();
    bodyFormData.append('key', 'apiKey');
    bodyFormData.append('function', 'getTeams');

    async function fetchData() {
        await axios({
            url: 'https://external.api/api/',
            method: 'POST',
            data: bodyFormData,
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
            },
        })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
            });
    }
    fetchData();
```

.NET request:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://external.api/api/");

        var postData = "key=apiKey";
        postData += "&function=getTeams";
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: CORS is a security measure that only applies to browsers. Your backend code is exempt from this, because there's no browser to enforce it.

Comment: Also, you can't send those headers (`Access-Control-*`) yourself. They must be returned by the API to indicate that you are allowed to send those requests.

Comment: Oh okay, I can undarstand, so as i thought, the simplest solution will be to use .NET app as proxy and then allow cross-origin communication between .NET and React apps?

Comment: Exactly like so

Comment: Thank you very much then, I will make it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CORS is a security measure that only applies to client side (browser). Browsers send `Origin` header whether you want it or not, and it's checked by the API to decide if it should serve you (by allowing the browser to go on with the main request).

You can send the request from the backend without issues, because there's no `Origin` header to speak of.

So you have two options:

- Proxy the API call from your backend
- Ask API to allow requests from the app's origin `https://$domain:$port`.

If the API is in your control, this should be easy, if not, proxying is a more straightforward solution.

### References

- [CORS - Is it a client-side thing, a server-side thing, or a transport level thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36958999/cors-is-it-a-client-side-thing-a-server-side-thing-or-a-transport-level-thin)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS